# STR function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

```
SELECT ltrim (STR (1234.34968311,44,16));
```

**Result:** 1234.3496831099999000

```
SELECT ltrim (STR (123.34968311,44,16));
```

**Result:** 123.3496831100000000

Can someone please help me to understand why the first query returns the varchar value which is not exactly the same as the input.

Answer (score 0):

Because STR operates on a FLOAT datatype so your decimal number constant is converted to a FLOAT before being transformed into a VARCHAR of the requested size. And as we all know, FLOAT values are an approximation of the number you thought you would get :-) so you end up with differing values after the decimal point.

For example, try STR (1234.1,44,16) and you get 1234.0999999999999000.

If you read the manual at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx it says `float_expression - Is an expression of approximate numeric (float) data type with a decimal point`. Yes, APPROXIMATE.